# Conectar dos aplicaciones mediante sockets

Tags: python, python-3.x, socket

Bueno mi problema es el siguiente:

Estamos comenzando a ver el tema de sockets y tengo estos ejemplos:

CLIENTE:

```
import socket
host = "localhost"
port = 9999
socket1 = socket.socket()
socket1.connect((host, port))
try:
    while(True):
        cadena = input("Mensaje para enviar al servidor: ")
        socket1.send(cadena.encode(encoding='utf-8'))
        print("se ha enviado la cadena: ", cadena)
        CadenaRecServidor = socket1.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
        print("El servidor responde: ", CadenaRecServidor)
except Exception as e:
    print("error", e)
socket1.close()
```

SERVIDOR:

```
import socketserver


class     MiTcpHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        try:
            self.cadena =     self.request.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
            print("Cliente:", self.cadena)
            self.CadenaSendServer =     input("Sevidor: ")
            self.request.send(self.CadenaSendServer.encode(
                encoding='utf-8',     errors='strict'))
        except Exception as e:
            print("error", e)


host = "localhost"
port = 9999
server1 = socketserver.TCPServer((host, port), MiTcpHandler)
print("Servidor Corriendo")
server1.serve_forever()
```

Mi problema es que al ejecutarlos se conectan sin problemas. Primero envío un mensaje desde cliente a servidor.
Luego respondo desde el servidor al cliente con otro mensaje.
El problema es que al intentar enviar nuevamente un tercer mensaje desde cliente, el programa (solo cliente, servidor si permanece activo) se cierra inesperadamente y muestra el siguiente mensaje:

> error [VinError 10053] Se ha anulado una conexion establecida por el software en su equipo host*

Alguien por favor puede ayudarme con este error o que haya tenido experiencia en estos casos. O al menos explicarme por qué sucede, si logro entender que pasa pues lo soluciono yo mismo.

Gracias de antemano, estaré aquí todo el tiempo necesario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error 10053 se produce cuando intentas escribir desde un lado de la comunicación en un socket que ha sido cerrado desde el otro lado.

Por tanto esto indica que el servidor ha cerrado el socket tras enviar al cliente el primer mensaje. ¿Por qué ha hecho eso?

Esto está relacionado con el funcionamiento del módulo `socketserver`. En este módulo, cuando invocas `serve_forever()` ocurre lo siguiente:

- Se crea un socket pasivo (es un tipo de socket de escucha que sirve para recibir conexiones) y se le asigna el puerto que le hayas indicado (el 9999 en este caso).
- Se entra en un bucle infinito en el que:

  - Se espera a recibir una conexión en ese socket pasivo.
  - Cuando detecta que llega una conexión, crea una instancia de un objeto de la clase que le hayas pasado como parámetro (`MiTcpHandler`, en este caso). En ese momento se crea otro socket (de datos) que se asignado al campo `request` de ese objeto.
  - Invoca el método `.handle()` de ese objeto, y espera a que `.handle()` retorne.
  - Invoca después al método `.finish()` de ese objeto. En tu caso no has programado ese método, por lo que usará el que heredas de `BaseRequestHandler`, el cual se limita a cerrar el socket de datos.
  - El socket de datos que se usó con ese cliente ya no existe (pero el pasivo aún sí). Se vuelve al principio del bucle a esperar otro cliente (lo que creará otro socket de datos y otra instancia de `MiTcpHandler` para manejarlo, etc.)

Por tanto aquí tenemos la respuesta. El *framework* `socketserver` espera que todo el tráfico de red sea manejado en el método `.handle()`. Tan pronto como ese método retorne se entiende que la comunicación ha terminado y por tanto se cierra el socket.

La solución por tanto es hacer, dentro de `.handle()` un bucle que repita varias veces la lectura y escritura del socket. Si quieres hacer que el servidor permanezca en ese bucle hasta que el cliente haya desconectado, debes usar como condición de salida del bucle la recepción de una cadena vacía. Es decir, si cuando haces `self.request.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')` recibes `""` esto significa que el otro extremo (el cliente) ha cerrado el socket. En ese caso el servidor puede finalizar `.handle()` para que su socket sea cerrado también.

Comment: Muchas gracias es justo lo que necesitaba. En mi caso  solo puse todo el código de try en un ciclo while y listo. Me salvaste la vida.